# Conda - gcovr offline installation

Tags: python, conda, gcovr

On my computer with windows 10, I can create following conda environment

```
conda create -n test-coverage python=3.6
activate test-coverage
pip install gcovr
```

Now, I want to create this conda environment on a Windows 7 computer with no internet connection. I checked this link

[Conda - offline install / update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577527/conda-offline-install-update)

but I couldn't find the package

> gcovr.tar.bz2

How can I install gcovr on an offline computer? Where can I find the current package of gcovr to download?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try cloning the [gcovr GitHub repo](https://github.com/gcovr/gcovr/) on a computer with internet access. Then, move the repo over to the offline computer.

The repo contains a setup.py file that you could use to install gcovr.

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you very much!