# Impossible to install python package with anaconda on corporate laptop

Tags: ssl, package, anaconda, plotly

I have anaconda install on my corporate laptop. I want to install 2 python packages( Potply & Fuzzywuzzy) but each time I try I have the same error message

```
Solving environment: failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url 
<https://repo.anaconda.com/pk
gs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on 
your way.


If your current network has https://www.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

ConnectTimeout(MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool
(host='repo.anaconda.com',pot
 =443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.bz2 
(Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x00000000054D45F8>, 'Connection to repo.anaconda.com timed out. 
(connect timeout=9.
15)'))"))
```

I have tried to use use the command :

```
conda config --set ssl_verify no
```

or

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

but none of them are working for me. Also because it's my company laptop I am not admin so I am not able to change the firewall and connection properties and I am not able to contact the service desk to help  me on that.

So I 'll be more than happy to hear your solution(s).

Comment: "I am not able to contact the service desk to help me on that." If you need for your job some tools on your company laptop and you are unable to install them because of some policies, this is not a programming question as trying to evade companies policies can backfire quite a lot. This is a problem you need to discuss with your manager: you either have the tools you need to do your job properly or you do not. It is up your manager to tell you either to use other tools that you can install or make sure that the local policies allow you to do your job. Doing anything else might risk your place

Comment: You are totally right with that. I have to specify that I am allow to use Anaconda ( jupyter ) we ask a specific request for me at the time. but If I contact the help desk it will take me at least 6 days and my request is pretty urgent that why I said "I am not able to contact the IT support"

Comment: If you can get the packages at `tar.bz2` archives it seems `conda` can install them directly without the network. Look at ansers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577527/conda-offline-install-update

Comment: "Connection to repo.anaconda.com timed out" means a network problem. Changing the `ssl_verify` switch will never help in that case, as the "SSL verify" step is during the TLS handshake (verifying certificates) and for that to happen you already need to be connected to the remote host. Here you do not seem to be able to connect at all, due to a firewall based on your company policies.