# Plotly package no module named 'retrying'

Tags: python, anaconda, plotly, offline

I searched for a long time for solution about my problem but I wasn't able to find.
I'm using anaconda with python 3.7.4.
When I try to launch my app.py file, I got this error.
Of course, I downloaded Plotly 4.6 using the tar.bz2 file and using "conda install plotly4.6.0.tar.bz2" (I needed this as i do it offline).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 9, in <module>
    import plotly
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\__init__.py", line 30,
 in <module>
    from plotly import (
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\__init__.py", line
1, in <module>
    from ._orca import to_image, write_image
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\plotly\io\_orca.py", line 14,
 in <module>
    import retrying
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'retrying'
```

I have no idea where this problem is coming from.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried pip install retrying inside your conda environment? Seems like it's not installed: https://pypi.org/project/retrying/

Comment: It worked, thank you I didn't understand what was 'retrying' but yes it's written it's a module.

Comment: The issue here is that conda install <file.bz2> will not install any dependencies.

Comment: This may help you find a better way to do offline installation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41577527/2272172

Comment: Yes, thank you that's what I was doing but I didn't understand I had to install retying package.