# Anaconda enterprise connection to cloud vs. 'offline'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, anaconda, data-science

On my company PC, I do not have full permissions to install Python packages(usually this has to be requested for approval from IT, which is very painful and takes a very long time).

I am thinking to ask my manager to invest in Anaconda Enterprise so that the security aspect of open source Python use will not be an issue anymore. However, also to consider, my boss is looking to move to the cloud and I was wondering if Anaconda Enterprise can be used interchangeably on-premise (offline from cloud, i.e., no use of cloud storage or cloud compute resources) and when needed for big data processing, switched to 'cloud mode' by connecting to any of AWS, GCP, Azure to rent GPU instances? Any advice welcome.

Comment: Ask Anaconda Enterprise support - this sounds off topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that can be a good approach for your company, I used it in many projects on GCP and IBM cloud over Debian 7,8 and 9, and is a good approach, you can also depend on your need to create a package channel with the enterprise version and manage the permissions over your packages and it has a deploying tool where you can manage the deploys and audit the different for projects and API's as well also track the deployments and assign them to owners.

You can switch your server nodes to different servers or add and remove as well when you work with those depending on your environment can be difficult at the beginning but is pretty good after implemented.

Below are some links where you can see more information about what I'm talking about:

[using-anaconda-enterprise](https://enterprise-docs.anaconda.com/en/latest/data-science-workflows/index.html#using-anaconda-enterprise)

[conda-offline-install-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577527/conda-offline-install-update)

[server-nodes](https://enterprise-docs.anaconda.com/en/latest/admin/resources/add-remove-node.html#adding-and-removing-nodes)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your preferences it may not be necessary to use anaconda enterprise on GCP. If you're boss is looking to move to the cloud then GCP has some great options for analyzing big data. Using the AI Platform you can deploy a new instance choose R, Python, CUDA, TensorFlow etc. Once the instance is deployed you can start your data preprocessing. Install whatever libraries you desire, Numpy, Scipy, Pandas, Matplotlib etc. And start your data manipulation.

If using something like Jupyter Notebooks you can use that offline to prepare your work before entering the GCP platform to run the Model Training.

Oh, also GCP has many labs to test out their Data Science platform.

https://www.qwiklabs.com/quests/43

GCP has many free promos these days below is a link to one.

[GCP - Build your cloud skills for free with Google Cloud](https://inthecloud.withgoogle.com/free-training-21/register.html)

[Step by step usage for AI Platform](https://medium.com/google-cloud/hands-on-big-data-analysis-on-gcp-using-ai-platform-notebooks-3470377f7c67)