# Python installation on offline computer

Tags: python, conda

I want to update my python version in an offline computer.

Currently the offline computer using the base env with coda version 4.5.4 and python version 3.6.5
I want to update the python version to 3.7+.

I installed on the offline computer the python 3.7.4 official installation for windows but I am not sure how to get the conda env to update to 3.7.4 as well.

Is it possible to get the env to update just by installing the official installation (that I already installed)?

If not, what is the correct way to update the python version?

It is a little problmatic to transfer files to the offline network so I prefer to be able to update the python version with the installation I already installed.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda - offline install / update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41577527/conda-offline-install-update)

Comment: No, you cannot update python in your conda env with the installer you can download from python.org. That just installs a completely new instance of python. You need to download a conda package, transfer it to the machine and then install it

Comment: Thank you very much, I did find the link you added but I wanted to know if it is possible to update from the installer (which you answered no). Thank you!